# bind_rows() error: by reading in a function?

Tags: r, data.table

This block runs below, and produces `df_all` as intended, but when I uncomment the single function at the top (not even apply it here but I do need for other things) and rerun the same block, I get: `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id): Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a function`

```
library(data.table)

#  addxtoy_newy_csv <- function(df) {
#    zdf1 <- df %>% filter(Variable == "s44") 
#    setDT(df)
#    setDT(zdf1)
#    df[zdf1, Value := Value + i.Value, on=.(tstep, variable, Scenario)]
#    setDF(df)  
#}

tstep <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 5)
Variable <- c(rep(c("v"), 5), rep(c("w"), 5), rep(c("x"), 5), rep(c("y"), 5), rep(c("x"), 5))  
Value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,33,22,44,57,5,3,2,1,2,3,34,24,11,11,7)
Scenario <- c(rep(c("i"), 20), rep(c("j"), 5) ) 
df1 <- data.frame(tstep, Variable, Value, Scenario)

tstep <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
Variable <- rep(c("x"), 5) 
Value <- c(100, 34, 100,22, 100)
Scenario <- c(rep(c("i"), 5))
df2<- data.frame(tstep, Variable, Value, Scenario)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, Value := Value + i.Value, on=.(tstep, Variable, Scenario)]
setDF(df1)

df_all <- mget(ls(pattern="df*")) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: you can use `df_all <- rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern="df*")), use.names=TRUE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern you use in `ls()` will match any object with a "d" in its name, so `addxtoy_newy_csv` gets included in the list of object names. The `f*` in your pattern means you currently search for "d, followed by zero or more f's". I think a safer pattern to use would be `^df.*`, to match objects that start with "df":

```
df1 = data.frame(x = 1:3)
df2 = data.frame(x = 4:6)

adder = function(x) x + 1

ls(pattern = "df*")
ls(pattern = "^df.*")
```